# How to create a shadow border inside a LinearLayout or EditText in android?

Tags: android, android-background, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

[image]

How to add a shadow border on 4 sides of an edit text as shown in the image? Applied below code but it creates a shadow on single side only.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFBDBDBD"
        android:centerColor="#65FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#C3C3C3" />
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Did my answer help solving your problem? Or do you need further help?

Comment: @DEX7RA not solved yet. Still looking for solution

Comment: Could you explain in depth what exactly you are looking for? Seems 4 people gave other solution of missleading  question telling. That would help a lot and I'm sure I will have a solution for you :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use elevation like :-

```
android:elevation="5dp"
```

elevation worked as Z-index.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `width` and `color` inside the `shape` tag.

It will look like this:

```
<stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#bfafb2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First create this background `drawable` with a `rectangle`, round `corner` and a `stroke` in grey. Called `background_drawable.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#C3C3C3"/>
</shape>
```

After that you set this as `android:background=""` in your `LinearLayout` and `EditText`, both widgets have `android:elevation="2dp"` for it's shadow on each sites matching the `stroke` of the `rectangle`. Here is your layout called `activity_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/background_drawable"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_drawable"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="10dp"/>
```

The final result will look like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNSwz.jpg).